# Server dropping or disallowing more than one machine from same network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, vps

I have asked everywhere and nobody seems to be able to help.

I have a VPS on Contabo. It used to be Ubuntu 14.04 and I updated this year to Ubuntu 16.04. I think the problem started around that time, so maybe it's related to the Distribution upgrade.

Whenever 2 machines are on the same network, only one will be able to connect to the VPS, either see a website hosted in it or ssh to it. Pinging works ok, both computers can ping the machine, but as long as both have the same public IP (being in the same network obviously), only one of them will connect. 
It doesn't matter if it's mail, https, owncloud, ssh, or anything on the server besides pinging. Any of those connections/ports will yield a "Connection Timeout" either on the browser or terminal of the computer not being allowed.

I have disabled UFW, flushed all rules on iptables and the problem still exists.

I am pretty positive that in most cases, my MacbookPro with Mojave 10.14.2 is involved. I have reproduced the issue in at least 3 different networks with 4 different devices. I use certificates to access the server via SSH, but username/password logins are allowed. In any case it's not a problem solely of SSH but all connections as I wrote.

I don't know what else to try and I am even thinking of just reinstalling everything from scratch (which would be a nightmare), but I just cannot work with my partner at the same time in the same office, without me having to connect to VPN to just have a different Public IP so he can access the server.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely it's whatever you are using to do IPv4 NAT in your office. Start there.

Comment: Hey Michael! Thanks for your reply! As I said it’s 3 different locations so far that I have observed this. Therefore I tend to think it’s not the location but the server or something in the server infrastructure.